# Subfig label positioning

Tags: positioning, captions, subfloats, subcaption

Can anyone tell me how to change the horizontal position of subfigure labels?

I have:

```
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,position=top}
```

Is there something like:

```
 {position=topleft}
```

to place the label in the top left corner of my subfigures?
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Hint: you can highlight code either by pressing the `{}` button above the edit window or by indenting with 4 spaces, or for inline code check [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).

Answer (score 20):

Here's one possible solution using the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) and [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\begin{figure}
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{image1}\label{fig:sub1}}\quad%
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{image2}\label{fig:sub2}}%
  \caption{Two subfigures with their caption beside}\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I get subcaptions as well?

Comment: @MLT although related to the original question, your requirement can't be tackled with the approach mentioned in my answer (the question only asks for labels and that's exactly what `\sidesubfloat` does; it places the labels beside the subfigures). The best thing to do would be for you to ask a [`follow-up`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) question.

Answer (score 14):

A simple way of doing it is to use `singlelinecheck=off` and `justification=raggedright` together. Below is an example that creates a bolded caption with left alignment for subfigures only:

- singlelinecheck=off means that the justification setting is used
  even when the caption is only a single line long.
- if singlelinecheck=on, then caption is always centered when the caption
  is only one line.
- caption label is bold, the caption text normal.
- justification is raggedright (i.e. left aligned)

`\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=top, labelfont=bf,textfont=normalfont,singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright}`

The above will place the caption on top of the figure left aligned. It will not place it on the side as Gonzalo example did, but I think this is what the original question was about