# Subfloat: Label beside, caption below

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm looking for a possibility to put the label (a),(b),(c)... of a subfigure beside the subfigure and the caption below. So I'm tried sidesubfigure ([Subfig label positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64934/subfig-label-positioning)), which puts the label exactly as I want to, but I didn't find a solution to put the caption below the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{rule}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\sidesubfloat[description]{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\hfill
\sidesubfloat[description]{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there a possiblity to do that?

[image]

Edit: Just got another problem, when I'm adding 4 same size picture in 2 rows like this, the pictures are shifted:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{mysubfigure}{desc}{imageA}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=4cm]{imageA}
    \end{mysubfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{mysubfigure}{shorter desc}{imageB}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=4cm]{imageB}
    \end{mysubfigure}
    \newline
        \begin{mysubfigure}{desc}{imageC}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=4cm]{imageC}
    \end{mysubfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{mysubfigure}{shorter desc}{imageD}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=4cm]{imageD}
    \end{mysubfigure}
\caption{Two images: \subref{imageA} is imageA, \subref{imageB} is imageB}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `stackengine` (and the `varwidth`) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{none}{}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering, labelformat=none}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\mylength}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mysubfigure}[2]{%
    \def\arg@caption{#1}%
    \def\arg@label{#2}%
    \def\arg@ref{(\subref{\arg@label})}%
    \sbox{\mybox}{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}{\arg@ref}\end{varwidth}}%
    \edef\arg@reflen{\the\wd\mybox}%
    \edef\arg@refline{\the\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
}{%
    \end{varwidth}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \setlength{\mylength}{\the\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox-\arg@refline}%
    \setlength{\mylength}{0.5\mylength}%
    \hspace{\arg@reflen}\subfigure[b]{\the\wd\mybox}%
        \centering%
        \toplap[\mylength]{l}{\arg@ref}\usebox{\mybox}%
        \caption{\arg@caption\label{\arg@label}}%
    \endsubfigure%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{mysubfigure}{longer description than the other}{imageA}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=6cm]{imageA}
    \end{mysubfigure}
    \begin{mysubfigure}{shorter desc}{imageB}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=3cm]{imageB}
    \end{mysubfigure}
\caption{Two images: \subref{imageA} is imageA, \subref{imageB} is imageB}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not solution I'm looking for, because I still want to have a supcaption below each picture. I insert a picture to my first post to make it clearer.

Comment: @Thomas I'll check...

Comment: @Thomas I've "checked" :)

Comment: Hi, nearly perfect now, thank you. There's only one question left: When the two subfigures have different heights, they are vertically centered. What do I have to change for an alignment at the bottom (as a subfloat does) of the pictures?

Comment: @Thomas really good question which revealed a bug on my part... have to look into this...

Comment: @Thomas is this all right for you now?

Comment: @Thomas Then upvote/accept as you like. And thanks for the nice question. :)

Comment: Ah, damn, still not working perfectly... When I'm using it with 4 same size pictures in 2 rows, they are shifted. Can you tell me, what I have to change? Code is at the top post.

Comment: @Thomas: you should change the `\hspace` inside `myfigure` to `\hspace*`