# subfloat figures in two row with labels top left corner

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I want to put two subfigures in two rows but with labels(captions) in top left corner of each subfigure. like this but in two rows not side by side preferebly some vertical space between them.
[Subfig label positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64934/subfig-label-positioning)

Comment: This is a common issue.  However, please provide us with a minimal working example (http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/ is a good source), and let us know what you've tried and whether or not it has worked.  Welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: Have you looked at the `subfig` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `\quad` by just `\\[<required_skip_length>]` in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64934/subfig-label-positioning) example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\begin{figure}
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{image1}\label{fig:sub1}} \\[\baselineskip]%
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{image2}\label{fig:sub2}}%
  \caption{Two subfigures with their caption beside}\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can control the vertical space as you wish.

[image]