# How to fix image on specific page using latex,

Tags: floats, positioning, wrapfigure

I want to fix the position of an image on specific page using Latex.
Here is the latex code of my problem: The output of latex code is attached as pic. You can see, image either goes to back side of text or it comes to front of text and hides the text. Moreover, if the number of paragraphs or the amount of text before "\begin{tikzpicture}" command is increased then the image of cat flows to the next page (I have not shown over here, in image of pdf pages).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
 % for labeling the figure wrapped with caption
%
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig., labelsep=period, labelfont=bf, font={small, stretch=1}}
\usepackage[capbesideposition={bottom, right}, capbesidesep=quad]{floatrow}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=-50pt] at ($(current page.south east)+(-4.0cm,5cm)$) {
            \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=9cm]{a1}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

 \lipsum[1-12]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=-50pt] at ($(current page.south east)+(-4.0cm,5cm)$) {
            \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=9cm]{a1}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you loaded wrapfig but don't use it, and you specify `overlay` to tikz so it leaves no space and overlays the text

Answer (score 1):

You can insert wrapfigure into the middle of a paragraph, but in this case it isn't needed.  Note the `\intextsep` gap above the image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
 % for labeling the figure wrapped with caption
%
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig., labelsep=period, labelfont=bf, font={small, stretch=1}}
%\usepackage[capbesideposition={bottom, right}, capbesidesep=quad]{floatrow}% are caption and floatrow compatible?
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351561/subcaption-caption-beside-figure

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{wrapfigure}[23]{r}{6cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=9cm]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[6-9]

\end{document}
```

---

This version uses flowfram.  Note the use of `\nopar` when the column width changes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
 % for labeling the figure wrapped with caption
%
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig., labelsep=period, labelfont=bf, font={small, stretch=1}}
%\usepackage[capbesideposition={bottom, right}, capbesidesep=quad]{floatrow}% are caption and floatrow compatible?
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351561/subcaption-caption-beside-figure

\usepackage{flowfram}
\newstaticframe[1]{6cm}{9cm}{\dimexpr \textwidth-6cm}{0pt}% page 1 only
\begin{staticcontents}{1}% IDN=1
  \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=9cm]{example-image}
\end{staticcontents}
\newflowframe[1]{\textwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-9cm-\intextsep}{0pt}{\dimexpr 9cm+\intextsep}
\newflowframe[1]{\dimexpr \textwidth-6cm-\columnsep}{\dimexpr 9cm+\intextsep}{0pt}{0pt}

\newcommand{\nopar}{{\parfillskip=0pt\par}\framebreak\noindent}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet, laoreet vitae, arcu. Aenean\nopar
faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim elit, rutrum at, molestie non, nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros,
malesuada sit amet, fermentum eu, sodales cursus, magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque vehicula, urna sed
ultricies auctor, pede lorem egestas dui, et convallis elit erat sed nulla. Donec luctus. Curabitur et nunc.
Aliquam dolor odio, commodo pretium, ultricies non, pharetra in, velit. Integer arcu est, nonummy in,
fermentum faucibus, egestas vel, odio.

\lipsum[7]

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec odio elit, dictum in,
hendrerit sit amet, egestas sed, leo. Praesent feugiat sapien\nopar
aliquet odio. Integer vitae justo. Aliquam vestibulum fringilla
lorem. Sed neque lectus, consectetuer at, consectetuer sed, eleifend
ac, lectus. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eget lectus. Proin
eu metus. Sed porttitor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
Suspendisse eu lectus. Ut mi mi, lacinia sit amet, placerat et,
mollis vitae, dui. Sed ante tellus, tristique ut, iaculis eu, malesuada
ac, dui. Mauris nibh leo, facilisis non, adipiscing quis,
ultrices a, dui.

\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know wrapfigure command and how it works? but the problem is the figure flows to the next page if the text before figure is increased. I want to fix figure at the specific position at any cost. then what is the solution.

Comment: You can move the figure into the above paragraph.  You can use the flowfram package to fix the image and text on the page, but you still have to manually split the paragraph where the column width changes.