Mixing subfigures with floatbox messes up figure counter
Consider this example, where I mix a subfigure with a floatbox:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}{10cm}%
\centering%
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:top}%
\rule{10cm}{3cm}%
\end{subfigure}\\%
\floatbox[{\capbeside}]{figure}[5cm]{%
\caption{XYZ}%
}{%
\centering%
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:bottom}%
\rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}%
\end{figure}

\noindent \ref{fig:top} \\ \ref{fig:bottom} % (*)

\end{document}

I expected the output for the line marked with (*) to be

1a 
1b

but instead I got

1a 
2a

Clearly, the counter is messed up by mixing the subfigure and the floatbox. How can I fix this?

I'd avoid floatrow if you can. even in its own terms, it has raw edges. (unless it has been updated since I last tried it.) your best strategy would be to explain what you are trying to do and see if somebody can mix up a solution to that problem rather than asking people to negotiate a peace treaty between conflicting packages :-).

You can effect a caption beside an image by putting the \caption in a subfigure by itself.  \includegraphics goes outside the subfigure, although you might need valign (adjustbox package).

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351561/subcaption-caption-beside-figure for example.
