# Subcaptions positioning next to image

Tags: captions, subfig

I'm trying to get the captions of two subfigures to be on the side of the figures instead of below them, to be able to save some space and get them closer to each other. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance `:)`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Top view]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}}
    \\
    \subfloat[Side view]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}}
    \caption{This is the ``main'' caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this solution can help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351561/subcaption-caption-beside-figure

Comment: looks like you need \sidesubfloat see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64934/subfig-label-positioning